# Where does function_exists() look to decide whether a function exists?

Tags: functions, themes, function-exists

The documentation says:

> Checks the list of defined functions, both built-in (internal) and user-defined, for function_name. ( **SOURCE:** http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php)

Does the function merely scan the single php document using function_exists, looking for any functions that match?

For example if I have `if ( function_exists( 'get_custom_header' )` in header.php, will the function look for `get_custom_header` in header.php?

Or does the function look into other directories and/or files, such as functions.php or in other files in the wordpresss core(ie. the wp-admin folder or wp-includes folder)?

Comment: In all of the php parsed so far.

Comment: Since my question has been put on hold as being off topic, I have redirected it here http://stackoverflow.com/q/20426188/2115934

Answer (score 2):

`function_exists('f')` will check if a function `f` was declared before the call to function_exists. Therefor the direct answer to your question is - in the functions section of the interpreter memory.

The result of `function_exists` do not only depend on the file in which the function is declared and the file in which the call is made but on the execution path.

```
function a() {}
-- at another file executed later
echo function_exists('a');

// displays true
```

while

```
echo function_exists('a');
// display false;
-- at another file executed later
function a() {}
```

`function_exists` at the same file as the function definition (which is a trivial not interesting use case) will always return true because the interpreter parses all function before starting to execute the file.

Adding to the fun is the fact that nested functions are defined only when their parent is evaluated and all php function are in the global scope which might lead to

```
function a() {
  function b() {}
}

echo function_exists('b');

// displays false
```

while

```
function a() {
  function b() {}
}

a();
echo function_exists('b');

// displays true
```

In a big and complex code like wordpresss it is not trivial to predict the result of `function_exists` which is probably why core doesn't use this pattern any longer. If you have the choice you should use hooks instead.

Comment: `if(function_exists('do_the_thing')) { die('you are wrong'); } function do_the_thing() { echo 'thing is done'; } do_the_thing();` - Guess what's actually displayed?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** the php function **[function_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php)** simply scan function only in the file where it is in, But not in the included files which are after the condition of `function_exists`. So in order you want to check the function then the function with file should be included above the `function_exists` condition.

This will echo yes because the function look is included in the file before it checks the condition.

```
include('ext_include.php');
if (function_exists('look')) {
    echo "yes";
} else {
    echo "no";
}
```

This will not echo yes instead it will echo no

```
if (function_exists('look')) {
    echo "yes";
} else {
    echo "no";
}
include('ext_include.php');
```

NOTE: `ext_include.php` is the php file which has `look` function

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer is wrong. It is not `only in the file where it is run`. It is in every file scanned before the function is called.

Comment: The function from other file become exist once that is included in the file(contains `function_exists()`). In this file it is checking for the functions and says `yes`. Because here it is included in the file so it is exists.Correct me if am wrong @Waldermort

Answer (score 0):

When the PHP parser parses the files, from your initial `index.php` to the current file containing your `function_exists`, it reads each variable, function, class, method, property... literaly everything, and stores them in a large [Hash Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). Basically, the names of those methods/variables are hashed and used as the keys.

Now when you call `function_exists` it hashes the function name, and looks in that hash table for a matching key. So, it knows about everything up until the point you call the function, including what is inside every file included with `include` and `require`. But it doesn't know anything that comes later.

Comment: This is helpful information. Yet it is not clear to me how one could trace exactly what should be in the hash table at any given point(in the context of using `function_exists` in wordpress).For example, in my example code, I know that `if(function_exists('get_custom_header'));` will somehow look into my theme's functions.php file. Being rather new at this, I don't see any Include or require that specifies functions.php